# Is there any way to fill the empty week days cells(previous and next months) in mat-datepicker and mat-calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, material-ui, mat-datepicker

I'm setting a calendar to Help users to select dates, but i want to fill the empty cells at the start of the first week with the previous and next months

I'm using the [Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) from Angular Material.

hrer is a picture link explains more :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sajAq.png

Comment: Can you provide your component code please. Are you using a library? is it a fully custom component ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their API, you can't.

You need to create your own custom calendar.