# Need to show previous and next month days in the current month calendar with Angular Material Datepicker

Tags: datepicker, angular-material, angular7

I am using Angular 7 and material library to create form controls. I am struggling to show previous and next month days in the current month calendar. Means I need full week calendar.

And how can I change week labels.Like -  Sun, Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu.Fri,Sat

[image]

Comment: @Mridul, I have changed the weekday names but not able to add previous and next month dates. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to fill the empty week days cells(previous and next months) in mat-datepicker and mat-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656326/is-there-any-way-to-fill-the-empty-week-days-cellsprevious-and-next-months-in)